# Replace overlapping strings in php

Tags: php

I need to replace a huge amount of words and phrases in long strings, words and phrases might repeat several times.

I have successfully built a `preg_replace()` arrays and it works nearly well. The only problem is that the list of words and phrases to replace I want to have is overlapping, for example:

> "acid" ---> "replacement1"
>
> "light acid" --> "replacement2"

and it makes `preg_replace` to complain, as "acid" is in both, which is not surprising.

The question: How to build a proper function to replace words and phrases like in my scenario?

Comment: Why don't you use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) then?

Comment: Presort the replacement patterns by their length and apply them downwards?

Comment: Or use word boundaries in your regular expression

Comment: @arkascha Why not making an answer out of it? Then the question wouldn't stay open.

Comment: @hek2mgl As you like. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just presort the replacement patterns by their length and apply them downwards. That way longer strings will get replaced first. Therefore any contained substring in there cannot be replaced accidentally by other, shorter replacement rules.

Comment: An example would be nice ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl an example of sorting something by length? Come on... no code in the question => no code in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what I missed in my logic, thanks, mate :)